# Cron Jobs Run At Same Time

Tags: cron

In my cron job file I have two cronjobs defined:

```
#Yo1 MAILTO="example@domain.com"
*1****wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test1.php">/dev/null 2>&1
#Yo1 MAILTO="example@domain.com"
*15****wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test2.php">/dev/null 2>&1
```

The PHP files are simple just sending mails with different subjects.

The issue is that both cronjobs are running on the same time every minute, but as you can see I want them to run on different times. First - every minute, second - every 15 minutes.

Can you help me with this. I can't figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.
Please use the following code

```
#every minute
* * * * * wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test1.php">/dev/null 2>&1

#every 15 minutes 
*/15 * * * * wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test2.php">/dev/null 2>&1
```

You can use online crontab generators like http://www.crontab-generator.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test1.php">/dev/null 2>&1
15 * * * * wget -O - -q "http://example.com/cron/test2.php">/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now second job is not running at all.